# Differentiation Property of Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-series

I've been asked to show that the Fourier Transform satisfies a list of properties, and I can show that the $m$-th derivative of a FT is multiplied by $(-i\xi)^m$ by inductively applying the original differentiation property, but I don't quite know how to prove that property itself. For clarification, the property states that:

$$F'(\xi) = -i \xi F(\xi)$$

Comment: Hint: apply Leibniz rule then apply integration by parts...

Comment: Isn't it $(\mathfrak{F}(f(t)))'=\mathfrak{F}((-it)*f(t))$ or $\mathfrak{F}(f'(t))=i \omega \mathfrak{F}(f(t))$?